# SQL Split string to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

I have this problem, there is a string column in a table, the data in it is mixed but constant.

Ex.

```
{ "Supervisor": "you", "Number_SAP": "33333333333", "SUPPORT_level":"on,NBD2222x5; KeepYourHardDrive-MultiDrive PCYourDriveYour", "SUPPORT_active": "1999-01-31", "SUPPORT_required":  false, "Power_Consumption":0, and many others}
```

They are not arranged in the same way in different rows, the order may be different, e.g.

```
{ "Power_Consumption": 4, "Number_SAP": "22222222222222", "SUPPORT_level": "OFF,ddd333222x5; MultiDrive", "SUPPORT_active": "2000-01-31","Supervisor": "ME", "SUPPORT_required": "True", and many others.}
```

How to distribute to columns only the values it wants, e.g.

Column name:

| Power Consumption | SAP No | SUPPORT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Power_Consumption": 0 | "Number_SAP": "3333333333333" | "SUPPORT_active": "1999-01-31" |
| "Power_Consumption": 4 | "Number_SAP": "22222222222222" | "SUPPORT_active": "2000-01-31" |

OR

Column name:

| Power Consumption | SAP No | SUPPORT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3333333333333 | 1999-01-31 |
| 4 | 2222222222222 | 2000-01-31 |

Parsing would be OK, but it is limited to 4 items, but in my case there can be up to 9 items.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version. It's a JSON content, so you simply need an OPENJSON call (if you have SQL Server 2016+).

Comment: SQL Server added JSON support quite late in the game (2016 version) as Zhorov wrote in his comment. If you're working with older versions, you might want to try and convert that Json data to XML data (which is possible even in pure T-SQL, but might be kind of cumbersome) and then use T-SQL's Excellent xml support to read the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stored data is a valid JSON content, so probably the most reasonable approach is to parse the data with `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema (note, that you need at least SQL Server 2016 to use this feature):

```
SELECT j.*
FROM (VALUES
   ('{"Supervisor":"you","Number_SAP":"33333333333","SUPPORT_level":"on,NBD2222x5; KeepYourHardDrive-MultiDrive PCYourDriveYour","SUPPORT_active":"1999-01-31","SUPPORT_required":false,"Power_Consumption":0}'),
   ('{"Power_Consumption":4,"Number_SAP":"22222222222222","SUPPORT_level":"OFF,ddd333222x5; MultiDrive","SUPPORT_active":"2000-01-31","Supervisor":"ME","SUPPORT_required":"True"}')   
) d (Data)
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.Data) WITH (
   [Power Consumption] int '$.Power_Consumption',
   [SAP No] varchar(20) '$.Number_SAP',
   [Support] varchar(10) '$.SUPPORT_active'
) j
```

Result:

| Power Consumption | SAP No | Support |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 33333333333 | 1999-01-31 |
| 4 | 22222222222222 | 2000-01-31 |

Comment: Footnote that @Lukas should replace `(VALUES ... d (Data)` with `tablename_that_contains_json d` and `d.Data` with `d.column_name_that_contains_the_json`

Comment: It works fine, but I can't understand it a bit, can you help me?
Because I have the tables it contains.
Original table:
Select name, custom, no, data, from data
Custom column, contains the data we are talking about in my query.
Now it wants to display, 
Select Name, Power Consumption, SAP No, Support, nr, data from data
I am trying to do it like this 

  SELECT j.*
FROM (d.Custom ) d (select * FROM data)
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.Data) WITH (
   [Power Consumption] int '$.Power_Consumption',
   [SAP No] varchar(20) '$.Number_SAP',
   [Support] varchar(10) '$.SUPPORT_active'.
) j

Comment: @Lukas, if you want to parse additional columns, you simply need to add the appropriate columns definitions inside the `WITH` clause. Using `JSON_VALUE()` (as in your answer) is also an option, but with `OPENJSON()` you parse the JSON only once and you may define the appropriate data types for the specified columns. `JSON_VALUE()` always returns `nvarchar(4000)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top(10) Name, 
  JSON_VALUE( custom, '$.Power_Consumption') AS PostCode,
  JSON_VALUE( custom, '$.Number_SAP')  AS [SAP No],
  JSON_VALUE( custom, '$.SUPPORT_active') AS [Support]
FROM [dbo].[Data]

it works perfectly for me

@Venkataraman R thanks for guiding me to the right solution.
```

Maybe my solution will be useful for someone too